# Need help to Write a function that accepts 3 arrays and returns a string of duplicate elements in ascending order

Tags: javascript

I need to write a function that accepts 3 arrays and returns a string

Answer (score 1):

The [time complexity](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/3.COMPLEXITY.html) of your proposed solution is exponential. Using an object to keep track of the counts of elements can solve the problem in linear time and space. In other words, you only need to visit each element in each array one time, rather than *n<sup>3</sup>* times where *n* is the number of elements in your three input arrays.

```js
const getDupes = (a, b, c) => {
  const seen = {};

  a.concat(b).concat(c).forEach(e => {
    if (!(e in seen)) { seen[e] = 0; }
    seen[e]++;
  });

  return Object.keys(seen)
    .filter(e => seen[e] > 1)
    .map(e => e.toLowerCase())
    .sort()
    .join(",");
};

console.log(getDupes([1, 2, 3, 'd'], [5, 3, 0, 'd'], ['A', 'd', 9]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `trackClones` solution:

Just loop over the the three arrays and store each encountered new item in an object. If the item is already in the object, push it in an array.

At the end, `join` the array and `lowerCase` the resulting string, then return it.

**Snippet:**

```js
function trackClones(a, b, c) {
  let track = {};
  let clones = [];
  
  [a, b, c].forEach(arr => arr.forEach(item => {
    if (track[item] && !~clones.indexOf(item)) clones.push(item);
    else track[item] = true;
  }));
  
  return clones.sort().join(",").toLowerCase();
}

console.log(trackClones([1, 2, 3, 3, 'd'], [5, 3, 0, 'a'], ['A', 'd', 9]));
```

You can also use a `Set` instead of an object. It will be more readable with the use of `set.has(item)` and `set.add(item)`.

**Snippet:**

```js
function trackClones(a, b, c) {
  let track = new Set();
  let clones = [];
  
  [a, b, c].forEach(arr => arr.forEach(item => {
    if (track.has(item) && !~clones.indexOf(item)) clones.push(item);
    else track.add(item);
  }));
  
  return clones.sort().join(",").toLowerCase();
}

console.log(trackClones([1, 2, 3, 'd'], [5, 3, 0, 'a'], ['A', 'd', 9]));
```

Comment: if I run trackClones([1, 3, 3, 'd'], [5, 3, 'd', 'd'], ['A', 'd', 9]) result is "3,3,d,d,d" ... I think the OP wants "3,d" from my understanding no?

Comment: trackClones([3, 3, 3, 1], [5, 1, 1, 1], ['A', 'd', 'd']) would now return "3,1,d". OP wants "ascending order". You need the sort approach from the 1st reply ... kind of.

Comment: Calling `indexOf` on an array is linear time, I believe. That'll hurt on large inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The bellow solutions should work for `n` number of arrays and do also do the lowercase and ascending as requested.

ES6 Solution:

```js
function sortByNumberOfClonesPureJS(...args) {
        let flatten = [].concat(...args)
        return Object.keys(flatten.reduce((result, value, index, arr) => {
            let numberOfHits = arr.filter((v) => v === value).length
            if(numberOfHits > 1)
                result = Object.assign({ [value.toString().toLowerCase()]: numberOfHits }, result)
            return result
        }, {}))
    }

    console.log(sortByNumberOfClonesPureJS([3, 3, 3], [5, 5, 1], ['A', 'D', 'D', 'D'], [ 2, 3, 3, 3,'c','c']))

    // returns ["3", "5", "c", "d"]
```

Lodash/FP:

```
let _ = require("lodash/fp")

const sortArray = (arr) => _.keys(_.pickBy((value) => value > 1, _.countBy((a) => _.indexOf(a, arr) >= 0 ? a.toString().toLowerCase(): 0, arr)))

function sortByNumberOfClones(...args) {
    return _.flow([
        _.flatten,
        sortArray
    ])([...args])
}

console.log(sortByNumberOfClones([3, 3, 3], [5, 5, 1], ['A', 'D', 'D'], [ 2, 3, 3, 3,'c','c']))

// returns ["3", "5", "d", "c"]
```

To View/Test => RunKit: https://runkit.com/akrion/sort-by-number-of-clones

Answer (score 0):

```
function x(...args) {
  let c = [].concat.apply([], args);
  return c.reduce((acc,el) => {
    return (c.filter(e=>e===el).length>1 && 
        !acc.some(e=>e===el))                                        
          ? acc.concat(el)
          : acc
         }, [])
    .map(e=>(e+'').toLowerCase())
    .sort((a,b)=>a>b?1:-1)
    .join()
    .toLowerCase()
}
```